# initializing sessionFactory using spring with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, sessionfactory

I have a problem initializing my sessionFactory. Here is my BusinessStartup class which is trying to use an object called dataModelFacade which in a hierarchy is going to use the sessionFactory.

**BusinessStartup.java**

```
public class BusinessStartup {
    DataModelFacade dataModelFacade;

    public BusinessStartup(DataModelFacade dataModelFacade) {
        this.dataModelFacade = dataModelFacade;
    }

    public DataModelFacade getDataModelFacade() {
        return dataModelFacade;
    }

    public void init() {
        while (true) {
            //getData from database
             List<Long> submitSmFinalizationIntervalData = dataModelFacade.getSubmitFinalizationIntervalData();

            //send them for show

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000 - (System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the part of applicationContextDataModel.xml file which creates the sessionFactory:

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${hibernate.connection.driver_class}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${hibernate.connection.url}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${hibernate.connection.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${hibernate.connection.password}"/>
    <!-- these are C3P0 properties -->
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment}"/>
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${hibernate.c3p0.min_size}"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${hibernate.c3p0.max_size}"/>
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="${hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period}"/>

</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.connection.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">${hibernate.c3p0.min_size}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">${hibernate.c3p0.max_size}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">${hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">${hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">${hibernate.jdbc.batch_size}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.order_inserts">${hibernate.order_inserts}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.order_updates">${hibernate.order_updates}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data">${hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data}</prop>
            <!--<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>-->
            <!--<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>-->
            <prop key="*in">20</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingDirectoryLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:config/hibernate</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

actually I have these in my dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>ir.hossein-shemshadi.analyzer</groupId>
<artifactId>Analyzer</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <spring.framework.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.framework.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
    <cxf.version>3.1.4</cxf.version>
    <jackson.version>2.6.3</jackson.version>
    <rabbitmq.version>1.6.0.RELEASE</rabbitmq.version>
    <quartz.version>2.2.1</quartz.version>
    <javasimon.version>4.1.1</javasimon.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
        <version>${rabbitmq.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>${quartz.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Simon-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javasimon</groupId>
        <artifactId>javasimon-core</artifactId>
        <version>${javasimon.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javasimon</groupId>
        <artifactId>javasimon-jdbc41</artifactId>
        <version>${javasimon.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javasimon</groupId>
        <artifactId>javasimon-javaee</artifactId>
        <version>${javasimon.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javasimon</groupId>
        <artifactId>javasimon-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${javasimon.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javasimon</groupId>
        <artifactId>javasimon-console-embed</artifactId>
        <version>${javasimon.version}</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}\WEB-INF</webappDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And finally here is my error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [config/applicationContextDataModel.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:753)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5003)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5517)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1809)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(TCPTransport.java:683)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Idon't know why I can not paste the error completely here :D
**error (cont.)**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.IntegrationException: Error activating Bean Validation integration
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:138)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:276)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:401)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
... 57 more
```

**error(cont.)**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at org.hibernate.validator.util.LoggerFactory.make(LoggerFactory.java:29)
at org.hibernate.validator.util.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:30)
at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ConfigurationImpl.<clinit>(ConfigurationImpl.java:59)
at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:43)
at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:269)
at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:111)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:461)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.activate(TypeSafeActivator.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:132)
... 65 more
```

**error(cont.)**

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1858)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1709)
... 78 more
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Can you add your full pom.xml

Comment: @kuhajeyan Done :)

Answer (score 0):

**1)** A `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` with `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` specifies that the particular class is missing during runtime.

You have to provide one of the various **SLF4J** implementation .jar files in the classpath.

Comment: Yes you are right. But as you see in the middle of the post I've been added it to the dependencies of my project.

Comment: try by adding this dependency
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.10</version>
</dependency>

Comment: I did this but the same problem!

Comment: Extract the slf4j jars somewhere and check that class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory is actually in it?

Comment: Actually I don't use the way of adding the jar file directly to my project. I use the maven tool for dependancy management so It's guarenteed that the jar files are correct. By the way I checked the jarfile and it had it in this artifact: slf4j-api

Answer (score 0):

Probably your conflict occurs due transitive dependencies in class path

mvn clean dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.slf4j:*

```html
+- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.5.6:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.10)
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.10:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.12:runtime - omitted for conflict with 1.7.10)
[INFO] \- org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO]    \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.10)
```

may be you want to exclude them

```html
       <dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
  <exclusions>
   <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
 </dependency>


                <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
  <version>${cxf.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
   <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
 </dependency>


              <dependency>
  <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
  <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
  <version>${quartz.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
   <exclusion>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
 </dependency>
```